# C#-Roslyn :How do I Use strings to define fields?

Tags: c#, roslyn

For example, I want to define a field:

```
int i;
```

If I use SyntaxFactory:

```
SyntaxFactory.FieldDeclaration(
    SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclaration(
        SyntaxFactory.PredefinedType(
            SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.IntKeyword)))
    .WithVariables(
        SyntaxFactory.SingletonSeparatedList<VariableDeclaratorSyntax>(
            SyntaxFactory.VariableDeclarator(
                SyntaxFactory.Identifier("i")))))
.NormalizeWhitespace()
```

It so loooooooong~

How do I define a field by using string?
EX:

```
string str = "int i = 0;";
{Api}.CreateField(str);
```

Comment: You can use: `SyntaxNode root = await CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText("int i = 0;").GetRootAsync(cancellationToken)`. This will give you a `SyntaxNode` of type `CompilationUnit`. This node has two children, one that's FieldDeclaration, and that's the one you're interested in, and the other is EndOfFileToken, which you don't need.

Comment: You can also visualize the results of `CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText` API using [this website](https://dotnetsyntaxtreevisualizer.azurewebsites.net/) (it's a simple web app that I made)